# Excel 2010 Pivot Table - Percentage of Other Column

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, pivot-table

I have reviewed multiple other posts and other sources online, but am still coming up short.

I want to add a column which shows a percentage of 1 column to another. Here is what is going on.

My raw data summarizes what course a person has completed, whether they tested out of it or not, the amount of time it took them, as well as some other stuff.

Here is my applicable part of my current Pivot Table.

[PivotTable currently](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o7bdb.jpg)

Grey rows are summarizing data below them.

I would like a column which tells me the percentage of people who tested out of the course. So starting from the top I would have the following percentages:

```
22.8%
0.0%
0.1%
94.6%
0.0%
0.0%
0.0%
36.4%
0.0%
98.0%
0.0%
44.3%
0.0%
90.2%
41.2%
0.0%
93.9%
0.0%
0.0%
31.2%
```

Here is a hacked example of what I am looking for:

[Example result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/likhV.jpg)

Any and all help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: I'm assuming "6,820" is in cell A2:  In the first cell of your new column, type =B2/A2 and fill down.  Format the new column as percentage with 1 decimal place.

Comment: That is what I have done in my example. I would like this to be part of the actual PivotTable. Thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

Add a calculated field to the pivot table:

1. Click anywhere in the pivot table.
2. Navigate to the "Pivottable Tools">"Analyze">"Fields,Items, & Sets">"Calculated Field"
3. Type a name for the new field, such as, "Percentage Test Out"
4. For the formula, simply double-click on "test out" field, then type a division ("/") character, the double-click on "completed" field.

[Calculated Field](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dXycv.png)

5. Click "Add". The result will show up as a decimal. To change to percentage, go to value field settings, and change number format to percentage.

[Value Field Settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E74SS.png)

[Number Format](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IKjhx.png)

Comment: Thank you for your response. I have tried this to no avail. I am generating the completion count by counting a 'User ID' field. I then find the number of test outs by finding the sum of the 'Test Out' field (test outs are identified by the number 1, no test out shows as 0). I get a DIV/0 error when I use the calculated field:   `='Test Out' / 'User ID'` am I looking at this the wrong way? Again, thank you for the help.